# Block A City From Visiting my Website

Tags: ip, .htaccess, ip-blocking

I understand it is possible to block a country from viewing my website using apache, .htaccess.

I was wondering if it is possible to block everyone from a specific City (namely the city of Flower Mound, in Texas) from accessing my website. If that's a no-go, how about blocking all of Texas?

Edit - the reason why. There is a competitor company that is based in Flower Mound. I want them to think my website is down/offline. *cough* dirty..i know

2nd Edit - I do this because they tend to steal my work, change it in some way, and then call it their own. They are quite adept in doing this, and I can't call upon the law for help.

Comment: I'd love to know why!

Comment: +1 for why. this sounds like a great story.

Comment: What has Flower Mound done to you ?

Comment: But think of the children!

Comment: Edited with the Why...

Comment: Is this kind of thing in your roles and responsibilities or have you been specifically asked to do this my management - the reason I ask is that if you're doing it yourself then your management might actually NOT want you to do it.

Comment: Virendar - Your question, at least for me, is now entering the dubious side what with making your website appear down to your competitors and entering their establishment with a wireless laptop in order to determine what their IP address range could be.  You may be on the wrong site to get much help with these types of tactics.

Comment: On a personal note, if I knew what your company was in the business of doing, knowing what you've asked here, I would not purchase a damn thing from you.

Comment: Ah well I'm sorry for sounding suspicious haha, I updated my original post with some more insight

Comment: Law enforcement might not be good for chasing derivative works problems; but lawyers sure are. If you've got a good case, some will work the case "free" in exchange for a large portion of any winnings too.

Answer (score 2):

It's technically not possible to block 100% of all users in $CITY/$STATE/$COUNTRY . Reasons:

- Proxy servers
- Satellite connections
- Inaccurate/too-infrequently updated geolocation databases

How about finding out which ISP your competitor uses and then block an IP-range of that ISP used in the city?

If you want to try blocking the city nonetheless, take a look at [mod_security +GeoIP](http://blog.modsecurity.org/2010/10/detecting-malice-with-modsecurity-geolocation-data.html) (assuming you're using Apache).

Funny question/idea btw ;-)

Comment: Any tip on how I can find out what ISP they use? I personally live in Canada, but I can get someone from Flower Mound to enter their company headquarters with a wireless laptop, if that helps any...

Comment: Well I don't want to support illegal actions, but here are some keywords: WHOIS lookup, netcraft, DNS queries (dig, nslookup) etc.

Comment: ... or just email them and start by the mail headers of the reply.